# Adding value to a list in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm working on a Kotlin app. It requires me to create my custom data type (User.Item) that represents an item. I'm using a mutable list to work with it. However, I can't add to the list. I'm using Firebase Database

I've tried various Firebase tutorials but they don't seem to be giving me what I need.

```
val item = User.Item(firstName,expiry,userId,null,null)
mDatabaseReference!!.child(userId).child("items")

//User.Item
data class Item(
        var name: String?="",
        var expiry: String?=null,
        var donator: String?=null,
        var pickupGuy: String?=null,
        var location: Location?=null
    )

//User.user
data class user(var name: String? = "",
                    var password: String? = "",
                    var email: String? = "",
                    var phoneNumber: String?="",
                    var uid: String? = "",
                    var volunteer: Boolean?=false,
                    var items: List<Item>?= emptyList()

    )
```

mDatabaseReference!!.child(userId).child("items") gives me a data reference. I would like it to be a list that I can manipulate. I've tried updateChildren(), setting it to a list and then pushing and then using that as a new value but nothing works.

[image: Picture of my database]

The adding is done in AddItemActivity on line 94-95
Github link: https://github.com/dl1683/ShareEats

Comment: Could you update your question with the function when you push data to firebase, just to confirm do you initialize firebase in your entry class for the app ?

Comment: I do initialize firebase in my entry class. I'm trying to figure out how to push the data. All my other database fields are working flawlessly by using setValue() but it won't work for adding a new value to list. I've added my github link for reference

Comment: I didn't got your problem, are you trying to convert the node Item into a list, is that correct? or the problem is saving your Item class?

Comment: I'm trying to get my list from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I worked using the newdata push

```
val item = User.Item(firstName,expiry,userId,null,null)
val newData=mDatabaseReference!!.child(userId).child("items").push()
newData.setValue(item)
```